# Using Kafka with huge data

Tags: apache-kafka

I have kafka cluster of the three nodes. I produced messages to kafka topic with 1 partition and replication factor 3. Whats happen if my consumer work much slower, than producer? Retention policies and other topic properties by default

For examle:

Producer writes 10 GB/hour

Consumer reads 5 GB/hour

Retention = 5 GB and 5 hours

Available space - 30 GB

Whats happens after one day сontinuous work?

Whats parameters I should check to guarantee zero data loss??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent data loss you must guarantee the consumer is able to consume data at least as fast as the producer, otherwise you will loose data.
Kafka doesn't care if the data has been consumed or not, it purges data based on the retention configurations.

If you use replication factor of 3 it means every GB you write equals to 3GB as it is replicated another 2 times, so make your calculations accordingly and multiple it by retention time:

Total storage you need - GB/hr * Retention * replication factor.
so 10GB/hr * 3hrs retention * 3 repl. factor = 90GB (total across all nodes together!)

Usually one partition is not enough, more partitions will provide you greater Bandwidth for consuming the data.